# Meteor admin panel without Bootstrap

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui, meteor-packages

I'm developing an app with Semantic UI, and I'm looking for a admin panel (like the [yogiben:admin](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin)) that does not require Bootstrap.

Does anyone have a suggestion? I'm not that comfortable writing a whole admin solution myself, and the closest I could find was the [Houston](https://github.com/gterrono/houston) admin panel. I'm not sure if this package is maintained.

Happy for any inputs!